# call widget from within shortcode

Tags: widgets, shortcode

I have a shortcode in my functions.php which runs a query on a category. I want to have a twitter feed on this particular page.

I have a javscript option working on my page for twitter right now but it doesn't look good and will take way to long to edit the javascript ( in minified format ) to make it look good, so I thought I would use a plugin.

I installed one and it looks good but I need to call it in a very specific spot within the shortocode. I noticed as is, it calls the widget at the top of my page from within the shortcode which breaks the layout. I did some reading and it looks like using the_widget() would allow me to call it where I want and it did put text in the right spot. Problem was instead of putting my tweets, it put an error message. I figured that If I use the_widget with the classname of the widget as shown on this page that it would work

```
 http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_widget
```

for example. The twitter widget I downloaded is called "simple twitter tweets" and I figured that I could do

```
 the_widget('PI_SimpleTwitterTweets');
```

and it would work. I was wrong. `PI_SimpleTwitterTweets` is the classname of the widget. Am I on the right track and just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of this function (`the_widget`) is an array with some arguments that defines what are the variables of this instance of the Widget, when you are outside of a Sidebar "loop", you have to pass those manually, instead of getting them from the database.

I've found the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/AshleySheinwald/Simple-Twitter-Tweets) for this plugin, and the arguments are in the link ([AshleySheinwald/Simple-Twitter-Tweets/simple-twitter-tweets.php#L112-L138](https://github.com/AshleySheinwald/Simple-Twitter-Tweets/blob/master/simple-twitter-tweets.php#L112-L138)), and below:

```
<?php

//Set up some default widget settings.
$defaults = array(
      'title'               => __('Recent Tweets', 'pi-tweet')
    , 'name'                => __('iPlanetUK', 'pi-tweet')
    , 'numTweets'           => __(4, 'pi-tweet') // How many to display
    , 'cacheTime'           => __(5, 'pi-tweet') // Time in minutes between updates
    , 'consumerKey'         => __('xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'pi-tweet') // Consumer key
    , 'consumerSecret'      => __('xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'pi-tweet') // Consumer secret
    , 'accessToken'         => __('xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'pi-tweet') // Access token
    , 'accessTokenSecret'   => __('xxxxxxxxxxxx', 'pi-tweet') // Access token secret
    , 'exclude_replies'     => true
    , 'twitterFollow'       => false
    , 'dataShowCount'       => false
    , 'dataShowScreenName'  => false
    , 'dataLang'            => __('en', 'pi-tweet') // Language reference
    // STARTING NEW FOR 2.0
    // Time
    , 'timeRef'             => false // false = use old full hour ref, true if selected will use hour ref as h (twitter style)
    , 'timeAgo'             => true // true = show ago, false will turn it off
    // Intents
    , 'twitterIntents'      => false // true = Default: show Twitter Intents
    , 'twitterIntentsText'  => false // false = Default: Show text - activate to turn off text display and use icons only
    , 'intentColor'         => "#999999" // Default colour, light grey
    // Avatar
    , 'showAvatar'          => false // Show the avatar ?
    , 'roundCorners'        => false // Do we want rounded corners
    , 'avatarSize'          => "" // what size should it be - defaults to 48px
);
```

Check what are the values which are needed for each of these settings and then the widget will be printed correctly.